# Select current week using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, date, where-clause, dayofweek

How do I write the `where` statement that select records with `Date` field between `Sunday` to `Saturday` of a given date.

```
Data Fields: Id, Name, Date
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Where `date` is the date in question, how about:

```
    DateTime start = date.Date.AddDays(-(int)date.DayOfWeek), // prev sunday 00:00
        end = start.AddDays(7); // next sunday 00:00

    var qry = from record in data
              where record.Date >= start // include start
               && record.Date < end // exclude end
              select record;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime givenDate = DateTime.Today;
DateTime startOfWeek = givenDate.AddDays(-1 * givenDate.DayOfWeek);
DateTime endOfWeek = startOfWeek.AddDays(7);

var query = myObjects
  .Where(ob => startOfWeek <= ob.DateField && ob.DateField < endOfWeek)
```